# How do I force wifi authentication on Captive Portal?

Tags: wifi, captivenetwork

There are wifi that uses Captive Portal to authenticate. Sometimes it just don't open browser and not requesting authentication? Is there any option to force it? Clear some kind of cache ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about on the server end or the user end?  Every device handles these a little bit differently.  Often I just have to open up a browser and try to browse to a site to get it to catch me.  That's the only way I can think of to "force" it.

Comment: All mobile devices works fine, problem only with MacBook. Opening browser, restartimg MB not solving a problem. How to wait a day sometimes to be able to see authentication in browser.

Comment: Did you find an answer to that question?

Comment: Restarting device helped several times